# Extract part of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have something like `HDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEK`.

The outside portions (Meaning: `HDKLFKEHR` and `LDKFRLEK`) will never change, but `######`will always change.

How can I extract `######` from the string?

Comment: Either substring or regular expressions. Check them out and then come back to ask anymore specific questions.

Comment: string.IndexOf and string.SubString. Go read msdn.

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "HDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEK";
string part = s.Substring(9, 6);
```

If the middle part can change in length, do this:

```
string part = s.Substring(9, s.IndexOf("LDKFRLEK") - 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "HDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEK";
string sub = input.Substring(9);//sub would be ######LDKFRLEK
    string sub = sub.substring (0, sub.length - 8)


Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
    output :  ######
```

Hope this helps thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = "HDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEK".TrimStart("HDKLFKEHR".ToCharArray()).TrimEnd("LDKFRLEK".ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that regular expressions are powerful for string search and substitution.

The following console app example shows how to use a regex for this (this has flexibility for the inner string to change and for text around HDKLFKEHR and LDKFRLEK):

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Regex re = new Regex( @"HDKLFKEHR(.+)LDKFRLEK", RegexOptions.Compiled );                        
    static void Main()
    {            
        Match match = re.Match( "HDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEK"  );
        if( match.Success )
        {
            var innerText = match.Groups[1].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine( innerText ); //######
        }
}
```

The way that it works is:

- "HDKLFKEHR(.+)LDKFRLEK" is the string that is matched where .+ means 1 or more characters and (.+) means that this is a group in the match.
- match.Groups[1] is the 2nd group in the match which is (.+). The first group is the fully matched string.

If this is an operation that you are going to be doing quite a bit on strings then you can consider making an extension with the flexibility to handle different enclosing strings:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string EnclosedTextSearch(this string theString, string left, string right)
    {
        Regex re = new Regex( left + @"(.+)" + right, RegexOptions.Compiled );                        
        string searchResult = "";
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(theString) == false )
        {
            Match match = re.Match( theString );
            if( match.Success )
            {
                searchResult = match.Groups[1].ToString();                
            }
        }
        return searchResult;
    }
}
```

Then the use would be:

```
string theStringToSearch = "SomeOuterTextHDKLFKEHR######LDKFRLEKSomeotheroutertext";
string enclosedText = theStringToSearch.EnclosedTextSearch( "HDKLFKEHR", "LDKFRLEK" );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText ); //######
```

The following examples show some of the boundary cases:

```
string theStringToSearch2 = "SomeOuterTextHDKLFsdKEHR######LDKsafsFRLEKSomeotheroutertext";
string enclosedText2 = theStringToSearch2.EnclosedTextSearch( "HDKLFKEHR", "LDKFRLEK" );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText2); //empty

string theStringToSearch3 = "";
string enclosedText3 = theStringToSearch3.EnclosedTextSearch( "HDKLFKEHR", "LDKFRLEK" );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText3 ); //empty

string theStringToSearch4 = "SomeOuterTextHDKLFKEHRLDKFRLEKSomeotheroutertext";
string enclosedText4 = theStringToSearch4.EnclosedTextSearch( "HDKLFKEHR", "LDKFRLEK" );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText4 ); //empty

string theStringToSearch5 = null;
string enclosedText5 = theStringToSearch5.EnclosedTextSearch( "HDKLFKEHR", "LDKFRLEK" );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText5 ); //empty

string theStringToSearch6 = "SomeOuterTextHDKLFKEHRLDKFRLEKSomeotheroutertext";
string enclosedText6 = theStringToSearch6.EnclosedTextSearch( null, null );
Console.WriteLine( enclosedText6 ); //full string returned: "SomeOuterTextHDKLFKEHRLDKFRLEKSomeotheroutertext"
```

Hope that is helpful.